# PrestaShop / get custom product field - from Cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have 1 custom field in table `product` , field named `api_pid`.

I don't know **how to get this value from page: Cart**.
In `hookDisplayAfterProductThumbs` it was easy:

```
$product = $this->context->controller->getProduct();
$PID = $product->api_pid;
```

...but I don't know how to get this value in cart. I tried to edit file: `\themes\classic\templates\checkout\_partials\cart-detailed-product-line.tpl` and simple added `{$product.api_pid}` - but not working - empty string.

Regards

Comment: your declaring the variable $PID which has been assigned the value of $product->api_pid so in the template file you should reference {$PID} ?

Comment: $PID in hookDisplayAfterProductThumbs is other thing. I was tried to get api_pid in cart summary (only show it on the frontend), when all products added to cart are showed in the table with possibility to change quantity, remove products from cart or go to cashdesk